# EF Materialization is slow with complex Where Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following query:

```
context.tblBeauftPosMitarbs
    .Where(bpm => bpm.tblBeauftragungPosition.tblBeauftragung.tblProjekt.tblTasks.Any(t => t.tblZeitens.Any(z => z.Datum >= start &&
        z.Datum <= end &&
        employeeIds.Contains(z.MitarbeiterID))) ||
        bpm.tblBeauftragungPosition.tblBeauftragung.tblProjekt.tblZeitens.Any(z => z.Datum >= start &&
        z.Datum <= end &&
        employeeIds.Contains(z.MitarbeiterID)))
    .ToList();
```

- It returns about 700 rows.
- This takes 24s in LINQPad to execute.
- I'm using EF 6.1 Database
  first.
- The SQL generation is nearly instant.
- I tested the query in SQL Management Studio and it takes less than one second to execute.

I'm using

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

- `AsNoTracking()` has no influence.
- `Take(1)` has no influence.

Simplifying the `Where` (although it does no longer do what it is supposed to do then) cuts execution time in half (about 12s)

```
context.tblBeauftPosMitarbs
    .Where(bpm => bpm.tblBeauftragungPosition.tblBeauftragung.tblProjekt.tblTasks.Any(t => t.tblZeitens.Any(z => z.Datum >= start &&
        z.Datum <= end &&
        employeeIds.Contains(z.MitarbeiterID))))
    .ToList();
```

So my guess is that EF needs more time for materialization when a complex `Where` statement is involved, but I have no idea why, because the `Where` should only have an impact in the SQL geeneration and the execution time on the SQL Server, but not on the object materialization.

**Edit**

Here is the code for the entity class. PK is (`BeauftragungID`, `BeauftPosNr`)

```
public partial class tblBeauftPosMitarb
{
    public int BeauftragungID { get; set; }
    public int BeauftPosNr { get; set; }
    public int MaID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EinheitID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Menge { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PreisgruppeID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> NettopreisProEinheit { get; set; }

    public virtual tblBeauftragungPosition tblBeauftragungPosition { get; set; }
    public virtual tblMitarbeiter tblMitarbeiter { get; set; }
    public virtual tblPositionstyp tblPositionstyp { get; set; }
    public virtual tblProjektPreisgruppe tblProjektPreisgruppe { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried the following without any effect on the execution time:

```
context.tblBeauftPosMitarbs
    .Where(bpm => bpm.tblBeauftragungPosition.tblBeauftragung.tblProjekt.tblTasks.Any(t => t.tblZeitens.Any(z => z.Datum >= start &&
        z.Datum <= end &&
        employeeIds.Contains(z.MitarbeiterID))) ||
        bpm.tblBeauftragungPosition.tblBeauftragung.tblProjekt.tblZeitens.Any(z => z.Datum >= start &&
        z.Datum <= end &&
        employeeIds.Contains(z.MitarbeiterID)))
    .Select(bpm => bpm.BeauftragungID)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Are you shipping your program in linqpad? Benchmark it in near real production environment.

Comment: I benchmarked it in Visual Studio and it takes about 10 seconds, which is still to slow. I'm trying to improve it, because we got a couple of timeouts in production.

Comment: Please post the code for `tblBeauftPosMitarbs` class

Comment: I think than Any con that list will cause iterative or recursive execution on .net side and not are resolved from DB. In extreme case i've executed optimized query on d

Comment: @dotctor I added the code for the class